# Visual Studio 2010 Toolbar Layout Keeps Resetting

Tags: visual-studio, layout, toolbar

My VS all the sudden started resetting my toolbar layout & selected after its closed/re-opened. Once VS is reopened additional toolbars are displayed which I don't use - quite annoying.

I tried resetting environment settings via Tools -> Import/Export and Resetting Window layout but this did not resolve the issue.

Anyone experience something similar or any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Found that problem went away after I uninstalled one of the extensions that I had : VSGestures. VS is now behaving as usual :)

Comment: I have the same symptoms but don't have any extensions installed. Still looking for an answer...

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple instances of VS open, you'll need to close both. Close the one with the desired settings last.